# Conditions for finding a lift

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

The question: Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous path. Let $S$ be a covering space for $Y$, with the covering map $p: S \rightarrow Y$. Prove that the function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ has lifting $\tilde{f} : X \rightarrow S$ to the covering space.

My work/thoughts : I want to show that we have a continuous $\tilde{f} : X \rightarrow S$ such that $ p \circ \tilde{f} = f$. My immediate (dumb) guess wants to use $(p^{-1} \circ f) = \tilde{f}$. Certainly a composition of functions would give us a continuous function and we're done. My snag is showing continuity of $p^{-1}$. If we take an open set $V \subseteq S$. My guess is that either $(p^{-1})^{-1}(V) = \emptyset $ or $(p^{-1})^{-1} (V) = p(V)$. My head feels scrambled and I'm going to be cavalier with my language here, but wouldn't it be the case that $(p^{-1})^{-1} (V)$ is exactly whatever $V$ maps to in $Y$ by $p$?

I think my trouble here is really figuring out how $p$ plays with $Y$. We manage to shove parts from $S$ into $Y$ very nicely via $p$. However, we have no guarantee that all of $S$ is shoved into $Y$, hence the empty set part. However, if the open subset (say $K$) we chose has non trivial preimage, I don't think I can say anything about $(p^{-1})^{-1}(K)$. Sure, $p(K)$ is open, but I can't think of anything to say about $(p^{-1})^{-1}(K)$

Could anyone offer any guidance on how to move along on this problem, or give any sort of confirmation that I am doing things right? Thanks!

Comment: It feels a bit silly, but I also feel paralyzed making claims about $(p^{-1})^{-1}$, it doesn't feel right to say that  $(p^{-1})^{-1} = p$ I certainly don't think the inverse of the inverse of a continuous function is continuous without some extra conditions.

Comment: The problem seems wrong as stated, since many maps don't lift.   For example, if $f$ is the identity map on $X=Y=S^1$, then a lift does not exist for any non-trivial covering.  Also, $p$ is almost never injective, so there is almost never a function $p^{-1}$.

Comment: Re-reading, your wrote that $f$ is a path, i.e., that $X$ is an interval.  Then I agree there will be a lift.  To prove this, note that $p$ doesn't have an inverse, but since it's a covering, when restricted to small enough open sets it does.

Comment: I voted to close your question because it is unclear what $f$ is. You say that $X$ is a topological space and $f :X \to Y$ is a path. So $X = [0,1]$? Or do you mean more general $X$?

Comment: The question was stated to me in this form, so it's not like I am trying to confuse anyone either. But yes, sure. Let $X = [0,1]$. @JasonDeVito, So then after taking our set $V$, what is the formal statement? We argue that $(p^{-1})^{-1}|_{V}$ is a homeomorphism and thus continuous?

Comment: @user817965:  Start with $f(0)\in Y$.  Because $p$ is a covering, there is an open set $U\subseteq Y$ containing $f(0)$, for which $p^{-1}(U) = \coprod_\alpha V_\alpha$, with each $p|_{V_\alpha}:V_\alpha\rightarrow U$ a homeomorphism.   Fixing one of the $V_\alpha$s, because $p$ is a homeomorphism on this set, $p^{-1}:U\rightarrow V_\alpha$ is continuous.  Define $\tilde{f}(t)$ for $t$ near $0$  to be $p^{-1}(f(t))$.  This starts the construction of the lift.  Can you continue from here?

Comment: @JasonDeVito. OK, I follow the argument so far. But what's missing? For all $x\in [0,1]$, let $\tilde{f}(t) = p^{-1}(f(t))$ for $t$ near $x$? Mentally, I want to "slide" my open set $U_x$ along $f([0,1])$ and keep track of a corresponding $V_{\alpha_x}$ that "slides" with it in $S$.  So then the lift would be that $\tilde{f}(t) = p^{-1} (f(t))$ for $t$ near $x$?

Comment: That's the idea.  Now just work on making it precise.  For example, you could let $0< t_0\leq 1$ denote the first time $f(t)$ leaves $U$.  (If it never leaves, you're already done).  Pick an open set $U_1$ around $f(t_0)$ and repeat the argument with one minor change:  you don't use an arbitrary choice of $V_\alpha$, you use the *unique* choice which contains $\tilde{f}(t)$ for $t<t_0$ with $t$ "near" $t_0$.  Rinse, repeat.  You may find compactness of $[0,1]$ important, to convince yourself the process eventually stops.